Auto-layout shapes on a layer in KonvaJS
Is there a way to have konva fit all the objects on a layer?
That is, instead of stacking the rectangles here, suppose I had a bunch of rectangles of different sizes and I just wanted Kanva to put them on the layer in some pattern where I could see them (assuming enough space).
https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Drag_and_Drop_Multiple_Shapes.html
I know the masonry.js library does this, but I'm just looking for something simple that I don't have to do myself -- place an image, if there's room to the right, place the next image next to it, otherwise go to the next line (if there's room), otherwise then stack them with a slight offset.
If I can figure out the dimensions, I can do that myself, but I thought there might already be something.
Thx.
